# Spring boot mvc without template engine

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I generated spring boot project that included web and security modules. localhost:8080/login gives me following error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Circular view path [/login.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

I've set up controller that is handling this request (works for sure because when I returned requestBody it displayed my message) and I am returning "login". First thing that is new to me is that there is no webapp folder. Instead I found resources/template and resources/static. I tried many combinations but I always get this error. When I add thymeleaf dependency to my pom.xml then it finds my login.html inside resources/template however I do not want to use thymeleaf as I have already created webpage that has a lot of not closed tags.

So my question is how to properly set up and configure spring boot application without using any templating engine.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login() {
      return "login";
  }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813615/how-to-avoid-the-circular-view-path-exception-with-spring-mvc-test

Comment: Suggested there solutions doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to post the source to your controller so that we can see the annotations you are using to map the request.

Per the [Static Content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) section of the Spring Boot reference, static content such as plain HTML files, JavaScript or images can be placed under **src/main/resources/static** or **src/main/resources/public** (there are some other options as well, but these are probably easiest). If you remove the Thymeleaf dependency, and just place login.html in **src/main/resources/public**, that should get you closer to what you are looking for.

Or you can take this as an opportunity to make your login.html XHTML / HTML 5 compliant, in which case you can avail yourself of Thymeleaf's features.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer my question however I did found a walk around to using thymeleaf.

I added following dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And such property to applications.properties `spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5`

Now thymeleaf parses my html files without a problem.