# Could not resolve view with name 'htmlviews/index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcher' using javaconfig

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-mapping

I get such exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'htmlviews/index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1211)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

when I try to connect to fully java configured spring web service.

My configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"config", "controller"})
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/htmlviews/**").addResourceLocations("/htmlviews/");
    }
}
```

Initializer:

```
    public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MyWebConfig.class};
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "htmlviews/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

whole file srtucture is simple :

[image: whole file srtucture is simple :]

I am using Idea IDE (also tried in eclipse, same exception) and trying to deploy on tomcat. In `pom.xml`, I added 'jstl' dependency, but that did not help to resolve problem.
 Using `xml` configuration everything works well. I have no idea what is wrong with my spring java configuration, it is super simple, maybe I forgot something?

**Fixed it** 
Everything started working when I changed spring version from `4.1.0.RELEASE` to `4.2.3.RELEASE` . I do not why it does not work with `4.1.0.RELEASE`. Maybe someone can explain, just curious.

Answer (score 14):

### Problem

Spring is trying to find views under your **webapp** directory. Since you do not have any **view resolver**, Spring cannot resolve "htmlviews/index.html". In other words, Spring does not know what it is.
You have a **Resource Resolver** for your html page, which is OK because HTML is static.

### Possible Solution  1

In your **MyWebConfig** class, add the following:

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("/htmlviews/", ".jsp");
}
```

OR you can do this:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver= new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/htmlviews/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

**Change your html page to jsp page, I recommend that because jsp is simply more powerful than HTML.**

### Possible Solution 2

Pult all your **htmlviews** folder under resources so that Spring can find it according to your Resource Resolver.

### Update

It's rarely the case that HTML is needed in a Spring boot app. I highly recommend using a template engine (**Thymeleaf** is preferred). This way, the sensible default setup is sufficient for most of the multi-page applications.

Comment: Thank you for response, yous solution would be good, but I want to use `html`, then I can use `bower` to import web dependencies. Already fixed it, no idea why but it was because spring version.

Comment: Yea, no problem. glad that you solved this. my solution 2 should work with html.

Comment: ConfigureViewResolvers fixed this issue for me.  Cheers!

Comment: adding Thymeleaf  dependency resolved my problem. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to implement demo https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ but i was facing similar problem, To note- this demo only have html with thymleaf (no JSP) and I missed to add thymleaf dependency(reason of error) earlier it showed error

```
Circular view path []: would dispatch back to the current handler URL ..error
```

Then I added bean view resolver and it started to give error .

```
Could not resolve view with name..error
```

Finally it worked after removing the bean view resolver and adding dependency for thymleaf. Adding this made my project work.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Some more help I found to understand all this working at [How to avoid the "Circular view path" exception with Spring MVC test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813615/how-to-avoid-the-circular-view-path-exception-with-spring-mvc-test/20312339)