# Spring MVC InternalResourceViewResolver

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm a newer of Spring MVC , and I'm trying to config a simple controller like below ,but when i test it. I got

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

Here is my WebConfig.java Code:

```
 @Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return resolver;
}
```

Here is my IndexController.java Code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")

public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {

    return "index";
}
```

}

Here is my Test Fiel :

```
public class TestIndexController {

  @Test
  public void testIndexController() throws Exception {

    IndexController indexController = new IndexController();

    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(indexController).build();

    mockMvc.perform(get("/index")).andExpect(view().name("index"));
 }
```

}

**Every time when i changed the get("/index") to get("/index.jsp") ,i passed the test. but i just can't figure it out, please help me out**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid the "Circular view path" exception with Spring MVC test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813615/how-to-avoid-the-circular-view-path-exception-with-spring-mvc-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test setup, you create an instance of the `Controller` under test, but the context created for the test has no knowledge of the existence of your `WebConfig` and therefore, no instance of your `ViewResolver`.

Here is a quick fix :

```
public void testIndexController() throws Exception {
  IndexController indexController = new IndexController();
  MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(indexController)
                    setViewResolvers((new WebConfig()).viewResolver()).build();
  mockMvc.perform(get("/index")).andExpect(view().name("index"));
}
```

If you don't want to access `WebConfig` in your test class, you can also create a new instance of `ViewResolver` and add it to your `mockMvc` setup.

Hope this helps.