# ViewResolver exception with MockMvc Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I'm getting an exception when trying to write a unit test for a simple `LoginController` method that returns a Thymeleaf view.

Sounds like I need to specify a `ViewResolver` but not sure how to do that.

**LoginController**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {
      return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

}
```

**LoginControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class LoginControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new LoginController())
                             .build();

  }

  @Test
  public void testLoginPage() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("login"))
                .andDo(print());
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [/login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

Comment: "this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))" Are you sure about URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid the "Circular view path" exception with Spring MVC test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813615/how-to-avoid-the-circular-view-path-exception-with-spring-mvc-test)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27797981/1143427 is a good solution for your particular use case (standaloneSetup & no assertions on view content)

Comment: @ryanp thanks, that particular answer solved my problem

Comment: @ryanp thanks! The link which you have provided solved my problem!