# View Resolver setup problem in SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Error showing in the console:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>
> [Circular view path [login]: would dispatch
> back to the current handler URL [/login] again.
>
> Check your
> ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified
> view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause

**AND**

> Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler
> URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be
> the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name
> generation.)

Configuration File:

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
package com.BasicWebMVC;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
    
    
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
package com.BasicWebMVC;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                // URLs matching for access rights
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAnyAuthority("SUPER_USER", "ADMIN_USER", "SITE_USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // form login
                .csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                // logout
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

Controller :

**AuthenticationController.java**

```
package com.BasicWebMVC.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.BasicWebMVC.model.User;

@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login"); // resources/template/login.html
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView register() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        // User user = new User();
        // modelAndView.addObject("user", user); 
        modelAndView.setViewName("register"); // resources/template/register.html
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("home"); // resources/template/home.html
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**Application.Properties**

```
# Database Details
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#Spring Security login queries
#problem in this line
#security.basic.enabled=false  
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, '1' as enabled from auth_user where email=? and status='VERIFIED'
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role_name from auth_user u inner join auth_user_role ur on(u.auth_user_id=ur.auth_user_id) inner join auth_role r on(ur.auth_role_id=r.auth_role_id) where u.email=?
```

**Model :**

**User.java**

```
package com.BasicWebMVC.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "auth_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "auth_user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "auth_user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "auth_user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "auth_role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    

}
```

**role.java**

```
package com.BasicWebMVC.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "auth_role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "auth_role_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role_name")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "role_desc")
    private String desc;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    
    
}
```

How to solve that issue?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Changing `@Controller` to `@RestController` fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 2):

First check that your view resolver is configured correctly.In your code i could not find a view resolver being configured which might be causing the issue. In your application.properties you have disabled thymeleaf view resolver so spring won't autoconfigure it for you :

```
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
```

> If you use Thymeleaf, you also have a ThymeleafViewResolver named
>   ‘thymeleafViewResolver’. It looks for resources by surrounding the
>   view name with a prefix and suffix. The prefix is
>   spring.thymeleaf.prefix, and the suffix is spring.thymeleaf.suffix.
>   The values of the prefix and suffix default to ‘classpath:/templates/’
>   and ‘.html’, respectively. You can override ThymeleafViewResolver by
>   providing a bean of the same name.

Also ensure that you have the spring-boot thymeleaf dependency added in your pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using thymeleaf as the view resolver and want to configure it manually , add the following configurations or through application.properties will enable default autoconfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        var templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return templateResolver;
    }

   @Bean
   public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
       SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
       templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
       templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
       return templateEngine;
   }

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
       var viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();   
       viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
       viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

If in your case you are using **jsp** as a view resolver , you could configure that using the default configurations through the `appplication.yml` or `application.properties`.But jsp only works properly with **WAR**  and take care to add the dependencies necessary.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**If we do not register any ViewResolver explicitly, an instance of `InternalResourceViewResolver` will be used by default whose 'prefix' and 'suffix' properties set to empty strings. That means, we have to use full view paths in our application.If you do not do that you will get the circular view path exception because of the way the view path is constructed.**

About your circular dependency here is a related post: [How to avoid the "Circular view path" exception with Spring MVC test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813615/how-to-avoid-the-circular-view-path-exception-with-spring-mvc-test)

Comment: where is method messageSource() implemented