# @RequestMapping different behavior without @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a simple controller class exposing two rest endpoints.

Removing the @ResponseBody is giving different behavior for the two endpoints.

If removed from **testRest** method - **output** is =

```
"1..name"
"1..name..name"
"1..name..name..name"
```

and so on, finally **Stackoverflow** exception is thrown

If removed from **testSimple** method - **No Exception** , **output** is "Test simple", response to Postman is :-

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-09T17:20:02.511+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/testSimple"
}
```

Code is :-

```
package com.search.catalog.rest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String testRest(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam String name) {

        System.out.println(id + ".." + name);

        return "result is " + id+ ".." + name;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/testSimple", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String testSimple() {

        System.out.println("Test Simple ");

        return "Test Simple ";
    }
}
```

Comment: replace annotation Controller with annotation RestController, if you don't want to use annotation ResponseBody

Comment: @YogendraR - yeah that resolve the issue, however I want to understand the reason of different behaviour

Comment: added an answer, hope it helps

Comment: @bharatbhushan `@RespnseBody` converts response into Json if its not used then no conversion automatically

Answer (score 1):

Without `@ResponseBody`spring looks for `ViewResolver` and as you haven't declared any so spring will use default one `InternalResourceViewResolver`

By calling `../test/1?name="name"` you are experiencing `Circular view path` .i.e try replacing `return "result is " + id + ".." + name;` with `return "result is ";` in `testRest()`.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18815059/8385477) given by `@Sotirios Delimanolis` will throw more light on `Circular view path`.

But if you use `../test/1/?name="name"` then you will not end up with this issue.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

`@RestController` from spring docs:

> A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody.

When you use `@Controller` without `@ResponseBody`, the spring doesn't act like a pure rest end point.

Comment: The view resolver is interesting. Presumably you mean a _view name_. How is that view name then used and how does its use cause a `StackOverflowError`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'll update my answer with proper explanation