# Localize where the Spring trouble hides

Tags: spring

I'm trying to follow an official guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
I run the application. Then in a browser http://localhost:8080/greeting

Result:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Aug 29 10:32:01 MSK 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

That is something at the server side. Here I have what there was in the console:
https://dpaste.com/AXBQW2EPV

I believe I need to localize the problem. I suspect the problem hides here: Circular view path [greeting]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/greeting] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Am I right? That is the flow reached the controller and occurred in the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer explains how a `Circular view path` exception could occur in detail, you might want to read it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18815059

For the problem you have now, your can try following possbile solutions:

1、make sure you have the **thymeleaf** dependency imported correctly and **downloaded successfully**:

maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

gradle:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
```

2、make sure you have added this header `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` in your
`greeting.html` template

3、change `greeting` mapping name to another one, for example:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}
```

then visit http://localhost:8080/hello