# Circular view path in Spring

Tags: spring

How can I cope with a circular view path error?

```
package com.example.PrinterManager;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class ControllerPrinter {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getHomePage() {
       return "home"; // Breakpoint.
    }
}
```

The interpreter stops at the breakpoint. But then the error occurs.

As for the template, it is here *(visible in the picture)*

> PrinterManager\src\main\resources\templates\home.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways to solve this problem:

1: add a `thymeleaf` to your dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

if no luck, try next one:

2: change your `home.html` to another name, for example, `index.html`, then change your controller to:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerPrinter {
  @GetMapping("/home")
  public String getHomePage() {
     return "index"; // Breakpoint.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `@Controller` → `@RestController`,

For more details look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49854383/1706545)